# Ошибка ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

Начал изучать Python, скачал курсы с Фоксфорда и там такое задание:
Напишите программу, которая переводит число (возможно, отрицательное), записанное в
шестнадцатеричной системе, в десятичную систему.
Входные данные
Входная строка содержит шестнадцатеричную запись числа N (1 ≤ |N| < 109).

При переводе чисел всё работает нормально но когда используются буквы вылазит ошибка из заголовка

Вот сам код:

```
number = input('') # строка которую необходимо перевести из шестнадцатеричной в десятичную
A = '10'
B = '11'
C = '12'
D = '13'
E = '14'
F = '15'
if len(number) == 1:
    print(int(number)) # Здесь и в нижних строках не переводит в строку в int
elif len(number) == 2:
    print(int(number) * 16 + int(number))
elif len(number) == 3:
    print(int(number) * 256 + int(number) * 16 + int(number))
elif len(number) == 4:
    print(int(number) * 4096 + int(number) * 16 + int(number))
```

Возможно я неправильно перевожу строку в число

```
number = input('')
A = '10'
B = '11'
C = '12'
D = '13'
E = '14'
F = '15'
if len(number) == 1:
    print(int(number, 16))
elif len(number) == 2:
    print(int(number, 16) * 16 + int(number, 16))
elif len(number) == 3:
    print(int(number, 16) * 256 + int(number, 16) * 16 + int(number, 16))
elif len(number) == 4:
    print(int(number, 16) * 4096 + int(number, 16) * 16 + int(number, 16))  

Такое тоже не работает

    number = input('')
A = '10'
B = '11'
C = '12'
D = '13'
E = '14'
F = '15'
if len(number) == 1:
    print(int(number[0]))
elif len(number) == 2:
    print(int(number[0]) * 16 + int(number[1]))
elif len(number) == 3:
    print(int(number[0]) * 256 + int(number[1]) * 16 + int(number[2]))
elif len(number) == 4:
    print(int(number[0]) * 4096 + int(number[1]) * 256 + int(number[2]) * 16 + int(number[3]))

в итоге ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/1/pythonProject1/1.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(int(number[0]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A' 
Вместо A пишет любой текст который я вводится в консоль
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, что Вы вводите.

Answer (score 1):

При преобразовании строковой записи шестнадцатеричных чисел в `int` необходимо указывать систему счисления вторым аргументом. То есть у Вас в каждом случае должно быть:

```python
int(number, 16)
```

И ещё, насчёт задачи: `input()` уже переводит строку в число в десятичной системе. Вам нет необходимости производить другие манипуляции. То есть, по сути, если Ваша программа просто должна выводить введённое число в десятичной системе, она ВСЯ будет состоять из одной строки:

```python
print(int(input(), 16))
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116269/discussion-on-answer-by-v-mor--valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with).

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете либо воспользоваться встроенными возможностями питона и переводить числа одной строчкой:

```
print(int(input(), 16))
```

Либо, если вы хотите именно вручную переводить числа посимвольно (в учебных целях), можно использовать примерно такую функцию для одиночных 16-ричных символов:

```
def hex_num_value(hex_num):
    hex_num = hex_num.upper()
    if hex_num < 'A':
        return int(hex_num)
    return 10 + ord(hex_num) - ord('A')
```

В ней для чисел от `A` до `F` (и от `a` до `f` тоже) вычисляется вручную 10-чное число, используя код символа, полученный функцией `ord`.

Кроме того, вы должны брать из числа отдельные символы, т.е. ваш код:

```
elif len(number) == 2:
    print(int(number, 16) * 16 + int(number, 16))
```

Должен выглядеть так с использованием моей функции (один из `if`-ов для примера):

```
elif len(number) == 2:
    print(hex_num_value(number[0]) * 16 + hex_num_value(number[1]))
```

Вы везде берёте полностью `number`, а нужно брать n-ный символ `number[n]`, переводить его в 10-чное число и потом домножать.